# can't create child span from otelgin

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, open-telemetry, aws-xray

I'm using golang otelgin middleware to create a span for every request that goes through my go server, but for some reason when I try to create a child span to do more detailed tracing I failed to do it and I can only see the span from the middleware.
my code below.
main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/otelgin"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/propagators/aws/xray"
    sampler "go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/samplers/aws/xray"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/attribute"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlptrace/otlptracegrpc"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace"
    oteltrace "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

var svcName = os.Getenv("OTEL_SERVICE_NAME")

func main() {
    err := start_xray()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start XRay: %v", err)
        return
    }

    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(otelgin.Middleware(svcName))
    r.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        tracer := otel.Tracer(svcName)
        _, span := tracer.Start(ctx.Request.Context(), "sample-trace", oteltrace.WithSpanKind(oteltrace.SpanKindServer), oteltrace.WithAttributes([]attribute.KeyValue{
            {Key: "http.method", Value: attribute.StringValue(ctx.Request.Method)},
        }...))
        defer span.End()

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "healthy": true,
        })
        span.SetAttributes(attribute.KeyValue{Key: "http.status", Value: attribute.StringValue(strconv.Itoa(http.StatusOK))})

    })

    if err := r.Run(":8080"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func start_xray() error {
    ctx := context.Background()

    exporterEndpoint := os.Getenv("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT")
    if exporterEndpoint == "" {
        exporterEndpoint = "localhost:4317"
    }

    log.Println("Creating new OTLP trace exporter...")
    traceExporter, err := otlptracegrpc.New(ctx, otlptracegrpc.WithInsecure(), otlptracegrpc.WithEndpoint(exporterEndpoint), otlptracegrpc.WithDialOption(grpc.WithBlock()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create new OTLP trace exporter: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    idg := xray.NewIDGenerator()

    samplerEndpoint := os.Getenv("XRAY_ENDPOINT")
    if samplerEndpoint == "" {
        samplerEndpoint = "http://localhost:2000"
    }
    endpointUrl, err := url.Parse(samplerEndpoint)

    res, err := sampler.NewRemoteSampler(ctx, svcName, "ecs", sampler.WithEndpoint(*endpointUrl), sampler.WithSamplingRulesPollingInterval(10*time.Second))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create new XRay Remote Sampler: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    // attach remote sampler to tracer provider
    tp := trace.NewTracerProvider(
        trace.WithSampler(res),
        trace.WithBatcher(traceExporter),
        trace.WithIDGenerator(idg),
    )

    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(xray.Propagator{})
    return nil
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    depends_on:
      - otel
    environment:
      - LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8080
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key>
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret>
      - OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=sample-service
      - OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=sample-service
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=otel:4317
      - XRAY_ENDPOINT=http://otel:2000
      - OTEL_JAVAAGENT_DEBUG=true
      - OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=otlp
    volumes:
      - /tmp/awscreds:/tmp/awscreds
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

  otel:
    image: amazon/aws-otel-collector:latest
    command: --config /etc/ecs/ecs-default-config.yaml
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key>
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret>
      - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
    volumes:
      - .:/config
      - /tmp/awscreds:/tmp/awscreds
    ports:
      - '4317:4317'
      - '2000:2000'
```

Dockerfile

```
##
## STEP 1 - BUILD
##
FROM golang:1.21 AS build 
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY ./ ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /bootstrap ./cmd/server


##
## STEP 2 - DEPLOY
##
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /bootstrap /bootstrap

RUN apk update && apk add curl

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bootstrap"]
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that the aws ADOT remote sample was discarding my trace. I fixed it by using the default always sample sampler. although this is not the recommended option due to possible high traffic to your server/collector. so I will be posting the new configuration here shortly.